# How to make all the entries in a table verbatim font

Tags: tables, verbatim, typewriter

I have a large table in the tabular environment and I need to make all the text verbatim font. I know I can use `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}` for all the entries but they are just too much for me to do. It might take a whole day from me. I know there is definitely a way out. I would be very grateful if I can get help from somebody. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Verbatim font? Do you actually need verbatim or is the font sufficient enough? Than `{\ttfamily\begin{tabular} … \end{tabular}}` would suffice.

Answer (score 10):

The `verbatim` environment uses the typewriter font, which can be used in `LaTeX` using `\textt{...}` or `{\ttfamily ... }`. In case you need to type symbols that have a predefined meaning in `LaTeX` like `$`, you could (depending on the symbol) simply escape them like so `\$` or use the `verb` command: `\verb+$+`.

For the sake of completeness, here an example using `\ttfamily`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

{\ttfamily                           % begin of scope
\begin{tabular}{llr}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item}             \\
\cline{1-2}
Animal    & Description & Price (\$) \\
\hline
Gnat      & per gram    & 13.65      \\
          & each        & 0.01       \\
Gnu       & stuffed     & 92.50      \\
Emu       & stuffed     & 33.33      \\
Armadillo & frozen      & 8.99       \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}                                    % end of scope

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]